# Is it safe to slightly unscrew a (non-dead) light bulb so it doesn't complete the circuit?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, bulb, socket

It's dangerous to leave an open socket, but I have a light fixture that's too bright and I don't have a dead bulb to put in one of the sockets. Is it safe to put a bulb in but unscrewed enough that it does not light up? That seems like it could be more dangerous than leaving it open entirely.

Comment: Best if it is too bright is to use a light bulb of lower wattage.  A ceiling light without a bulb is safer than a desk lamp.  Problem with a loose bulb is the right distance to prevent arcing and from falling out.  Tape on the switch or unplugging the light is probably better till you get a new blub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly fine. You just want to make sure that:

- It is loose enough that it doesn't *sometimes* work - that would cause arcing, which is not a good thing.
- It is not so loose that it could easily fall out.

As an extreme example of this, my synagogue, like many others, has what are called "Yahrzeit plaques". These typically list the name and date of death of a former member or relative of a member, in Hebrew and English. Each year around the anniversary of the death (the Yahrzeit), little lights are turned on next to each plaque. A few times a year (certain holidays), *all* the lights are turned on. The bulbs are in place all the time, but not tightened all the way. To turn them on, tighten them. To turn them off, loosen them.

[image: Yahrzeit board]

In this example, you can see 3 plaques/6 bulbs lit up.

Comment: That's quite interesting and touching plaque. By the way, what are the consequences of arcing in this case, and how can I be sure that my bulb is not arcing (I have not observed it flickering but it may be doing so while my eyes aren't on it)

Comment: Arcing produces heat. (Think: arc-welding) Over time, enough arcing can generate enough heat to burn things up. Not all that likely in a light bulb socket - the big concern is damaged wiring inside a wall where (a) nobody can see it and (b) the wire is in a cable that is often embedded in very flammable materials. But if you don't see your bulb flickering at all then it is almost certainly just fine and I wouldn't worry about it. Anecdote: One time in my synagogue I noticed some lights in the ark that holds the Torahs were flickering. I was really worried about arcing. It turned out to be

Comment: LED bulbs on a non-compatible dimmer (not sure if it was non-dimmable bulbs or non-LED-compatible dimmer, but result in either case is often flickering). We didn't *want* the bulbs dimmed, so now we know "always turn them on 100%". But it had me worried there at first.

Answer (score 4):

If you just don't want the light from the bulb, unscrew it and replace it with one of these:
[image: bulb adapter]

Answer (score 3):

It's not unsafe at all. But have you simply thought of using lower wattage bulbs?